# getting content-length using requests using get gives correct result but why not with the head?

Tags: http-headers, python-requests, http-get, redirect, content-length

So I am bit surprised, while I was trying to understand `requests` module.

```
>>> furl = 'http://www.downvids.net/downloads/07275feaf477cc0f5a7a67cba965594d5c83/'

>>> resp = requests.get(furl, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'})
>>> resp.headers['content-length']
'7254371'
>>> resp2 = requests.head(furl)
>>> resp2.headers['content-length']
'20'
```

but doing by `requests.get` i think it is downloading the whole file to buffer from which it is getting the content length !!!

so what should be the correct approach to get correct content-length if it is the case of url redirects which seems to be because i tried `resp2.status_code` that gave me `302`

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345225/http-head-method-content-length-does-not-match-with-size-on-view-page-info?rq=1) is also seeking a similar answer, however I have used `requests` module ... he is asking in general !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a `HEAD` request, `requests` sets `allow_redirects` to False, by default; this differs from all the other HTTP methods where redirection following is *on* by default. See the [*Redirection and History*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) documentation:

> By default Requests will perform location redirection for all verbs except HEAD.

You can force it to follow redirects by setting `allow_redirects=True`:

```
resp2 = requests.head(furl, allow_redirects=True)
```

Your GET did follow the redirect (from the original URL to `https://scontent-b-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xpa1/v/t42.1790-2/1598692_10153946120225652_1024334852_n.mp4?oh=de27dad30979955f4e8fef28b85f9af9&oe=53D50345`); your `HEAD` request did not.

Servers [*SHOULD* return the same headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.4) for a HEAD as they do for a GET, but the RFC verb *SHOULD* here also means that a server may ignore that requirement if the implementation would be too costly or for any other reason.

You can always make a GET request that doesn't download the body, by setting `stream=True`:

```
 resp = requests.get(furl, stream=True)
```

Comment: so no need to use `requests.get` than, however could there be any situation when `requests.head` won't get the `content-length` even when `allow_redirects` is set to `True` ?

Comment: The server *should* give you the same headers as a GET would return; in practice, some servers could violate that rule still. There is nothing you can change about that other than use a `request.get()` with `stream=True` set, then just not reading the response body.